# Update a view scoped JSF beans' injected bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, view-scope, managed-property

```
@SessionScoped public class User {
...  //settings, attributes, etc
}

@ViewScoped public class FooController {
@ManagedProperty(value="#{user}") 
private User user;
...
}

@RequestScoped public class LoginController {
@ManagedProperty(value="#{user}") 
private User user;
public String login() {
    //handle Servlet 3.0 based authenticate()... if success, make new User object and slap it into context
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
    return "?faces-redirect=true";
}
...
}
```

xhtml pages include the login controls on pretty much every page.  The ideal would be that they are able to login, and the page will refresh and the existing `FooController` would have the reference to the currently logged in user, which conditionally renders buttons / elements.  The behavior is that the login occurs, but the `FooController` view is still "valid", so the managed bean never is attempted to be injected again.  If I navigate off the page, and back onto it [reconstructing the view scoped bean] the user bean is reinjected nicely... but I'd prefer not to have that interim step.   Any ideas?

I've tried various forms of `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().remove("user");` in hopes that it will re-pull it from session but no avail.  I do not want to tightly couple code in my LoginController to reference specifically invalidating a FooController or BarController or any other that refs the user bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out on the drive home, it was a lifecycle problem.  I was trying to get JSF to do something it shouldn't be doing to managed beans.

Instead of new'ing up a `User` object and reassigning it to the managed instance of `user` in `LoginController`, i changed the login method to look like this:

```
public String login() {
  //handle Servlet 3.0 based authenticate()... if success...
  User loadedFromDB = someDao.load(principal.getName());
  user.setDefaultPage(loadedFromDB.getDefaultPage());  // NOTE:  The user object IS THE MANAGED BEAN
  user.setDefaultScheme(loadedFromDB.getDefaultScheme());  //  This is the same object the view scoped bean has a ref on, so directly setting that object's fields proliferates that to any other bean that has the user in scope.
  ... //etc... not calling NEW, not reassigning object ref to user
  loadedFromDB = null;
  return "?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

This accomplishes what was needed.  Who knew, if you stop fighting the framework for a minute and just use it, it helps you out  :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to remove `user` (a `@SessionBean`), from the `viewMap` (a map of `@ViewScoped` objects in the current session)?

You should be removing `FooController`, the `@ViewScoped`, bean from the `viewMap`, i.e.

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().remove("fooControl‌​ler");.
```

This is what will get rid of the viewscoped bean and force a new one to be created. Then of course, you'll need to refresh the page anyway.

If you're intent on removing the session bean however, you should be accessing the session directly:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("user");.
```

That gets rid of the user object

Comment: Well, the goal isn't so much to remove the user bean, but to proliferate the updated User object to any view-scoped bean.  I tested your solution, which works, but `FooController` is only one of about 20 view scoped beans that could be alive depending on what page the user is logging in from.  [Login form is a popout panel, included on nearly every page].  It would seem an entanglement issue to have the `LoginController`'s code name 20+ beans to try to remove.